# Unable to map the subject to a Salesforce.com user AssertionId

Tags: community, sandbox, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, saml

I am new on salesforce, working on SAML2.0 using OKTA with salesforce. I have choose Salesforce(Federation ID)application on OKTA and follow the instruction given in OKTA, but failed to login in Salesforce using SAML2.0, It's come back as log out. I checked SAML Validator and find following errors.[image]

Comment: What do Okta support say?